# How do I change country in user profile on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts, user-information

I registered on Stack Overflow when I was in USA, but now I am in Pakistan. Is there a way to change the country so it is shown correctly?

Also I want to find my ranking among Pakistani users as well.

Comment: Your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165251/dave) location shows Pakistan...

Comment: @rene where is it asked before, do you have a link before closing it?

Comment: Not sure what you ask. The link is shown in the duplicate notice at the top of your question

Comment: @rene thanks for pointing out. Sorry for not noticing it. The reason I could not find that question is because it was not showing up in google probably because of keywords. Anyways thank you.

Comment: Please don't rollback helpful edits. We need posts to read clearly and your presentation of spelling (Stackoverflow) is incorrect. Also, we require questions be asked one at a time, so we need you to split them up.

Comment: I wanted to say the same, please dont edit my question. I have put it in words so it can show up in google and help others. They are constantly removing SEO friendly words from the question.

Comment: If you don't like people editing your posts, you're on the wrong site.

Comment: Edits are of course welcome. But if you make it the same as the original dup, it will again not show up in google. In that case this question has no value and should be deleted.

Comment: Check my search query, this question comes on top "change country name in user profile stackoverflow" -> https://i.imgur.com/cPwwqsf.png

Answer (score 5):

Trivial

1. Click on your profile picture
2. select "Edit Profile and Settings" tab
3. Type country name in location

**Note your ranking in that country may not appear right after you make the change.**

[image]